# Javascript variable interpolation with variable

Tags: javascript

I've got the following `JS`

```
var decSep_1 = true;

function radioButtons(stuff){
    if( decSep_1 === true ){
        return ','
    }

    return false
}

alert(radioButtons());
```

How can I make `stuff` in `radioButtons` be a part of the variable I am comparing in the `if` statements?

For example:

```
function radioButtons(stuff){
    if( stuff + _1 === true ){
        return ','
    }

    return false
}

alert(radioButtons(decSep));
```

Comment: This question sure gets asked a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that with `eval` this is possible: http://jsfiddle.net/f2f87ko5/10/

```
var decSep_1 = true;

function radioButtons(stuff){
    if(eval(stuff + "_1") === true){
        return 'ytjyjju'
    }
    return false
}

alert(radioButtons("decSep"));
```